# Simple error C program

Tags: c

Edit: Sorry guys, I am learning how to use XCode and did not see that there was another error. I deleted the program and copy/pasted the source code to create the program again and it seems to work fine. Not really sure what went wrong there. Weird that I was getting that error.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int heartBeatsPerSecond, daysInYear, secondsInYear, beatsPerYear;
    heartBeatsPerSecond = 1;
    daysInYear = 365;
    secondsInYear = 60*60*24*365;

    beatsPerYear = heartBeatsPerSecond * secondsInYear;
    return beatsPerYear;
}
```

Comment: When you try to run or compile? At a quick glance it looks ok. What compiler? What's your command line?

Comment: Cannot reproduce; programs compiles (with warnings enabled) and runs perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: void main is not valid C.

Comment: You are right jwodder, sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Try `unsigned long long heartBeatsPersecond, daysInYear, secondsInYear, beatsPerYear;`, `unsigned long long `means 64-bits unsigned Integer, maybe enough for your multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Your code runs here. It isn't correct, but it runs. Because your multiplication overflows (at least on my platform). I suggest you fix that overflow like,

```
int heartBeatsPerSecond = 1;
int daysInYear = 365;
long secondsInYear = 60*60*24*365;

long beatsPerYear = heartBeatsPerSecond * secondsInYear;
printf("%li\n", beatsPerYear);
```

Output (when I run it) is

```
31536000
```

Comment: I thought I had double checked the length permitted for a regular int and it was not a large enough number.

Comment: @vikingcode 31536000 fits into a 32 bit int, but with C you aren't guaranteed the integer is 32 bits. Elliott's platform may only have 16 bit ints (which won't hold your result).